# How can I return the selected items in View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created a web page using asp.net MVC with Entity Framework. I want to return in the View the selected items. If I select multiple data, just the last item return. When I debug, the array receive the selected items, but in the foreach loop, just the last query return. How can I fix this?

### View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownList("prof_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @multiple = "multiple" })<br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int[] prof_id)
{
   ViewBag.prof_id = new MultiSelectList(db.prof, "prof_id", "name");

   List<user> test = new List<user>();
   foreach (var item in prof_id)
   {
      test = db.user.Where(u => u.prof_id == item).ToList();

   }

   return View(test.ToList());
}
```

### Model

```
public partial class prof
{
   public prof()
   {
      this.user = new HashSet<user>();
   }

   public int prof_id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<user> user { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change foreach loop inside with this,

```
var tempList = db.user.Where(u => u.prof_id == item).ToList();
test.AddRange(tempList);
```

Hope helps,